# TYPO3 generate two Models with one Form

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I want to generate and persit multiple objects with only one form.

In My Form I have fields für Model Object House and fields for Model People, First 3 are for House and last 3 are for People.

Wenn I submit the form I want to create a Object for House and A Object for People. And the People should get the Relation to the house.

I tried this:

`public function createAction(\Blubb\Blubb\Domain\Model\House $newHouse, \Blubb\Blubb\Domain\Model\People $newPeople) {
        $this->houseRepository->add($newHouse);
        $this->peopleRepository->add($newPeople);
        $this->redirect('list');
    }`

Form looks like this:

how can I select which elements are for the House and which for the People?

Alternatively i tried set another form where i specified the name of Input like this:

`name="house[housenr]"` --> Then I got this error: Required argument "newHouse" is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove params from your `createAction()` so you can use methods

- `$this->request->hasArgument('foo')`
- `$this->request->getArgument('foo')`

for custom collecting fields.